# a Python program that reads in a word specified by the user and prints that word out x number of times where x is the number of characters in the word

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a Python code "program that reads in a word specified by the user and prints that word out x number of times where x is the number of characters in the word. Your solution must use a loop"

For example, if the user enters “John”, the computer will print
“John” four times since there are four characters in “John”.

I have done my other task for today though it took me a while it was to make a code that does the same but for the amount of words in a paragraph then prints them as many times as there were words in the paragraph.

```
 loop = 0
 print ("please enter a paragraph")
 word = str (input())
 words = word.split()
 number_of_words = len(words)
 while (loop < number_of_words):
      print(words)
      loop = loop + 1
```

I feel i'm not far off the same principle for the task I am asking help for, as my other does the same but with words not letters. May someone show me the most basic way to count all the letters in a paragraph then print them as many times as there is letters in the paragraph . I found one post on here that is almost the same but refers to files and looks a tad too complex for me "being in my first year at college"

Comment: Hint: look up `range` and then look up how to use that in a loop.

Comment: Being In You First Year At College, aren't you supposed to work out your assignments by yourself? :)

Comment: By the way, your original requirements specify that the program must deal with a *single* word, so what's that `words` stuff about? Hint: 1. read the word with `word = str(input())`, 2. obtain the length in characters of the word with `len(word)` 3. iterate enough times. Your loop is ok, the bit before it is not.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that your variable `name` is your input:

```
for _ in name: print(name)
```

`for` loops iterate through the letters of a string but since you want to print out the word each time, you dont need to use the values.

Answer (score 0):

python makes this extremely easy:

```
print(word*len(word))
# or with newlines inbetween
print((word+"\n")*len(word))
```

Edit: since you really need a loop just use the already suggested answer from R Nar:

```
for _ in word: print(word)
```

Comment: *your solution must just a loop*

Comment: @RNar: You could just use `for i in 1, 2, 3: pass` in the next line.  Nonsensical constraints ask for nonsensical solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(words)):
     print words
```

I think this should be fine.